# Django-Rest-Framework: How to build Async Directory/Folder upload and Bulk File upload

Tags: django, file-upload, django-rest-framework, django-views, asyncfileupload

So My team mates and I have been having a hard time with the efficiency of the synchronous file upload CRUD endpoints we've built and now we need to implement a bulk file upload(Directory upload) with either celery or asyncio(any other methods are kindly welcome).

***what I have working currently***

**My Model:**

```
class CompanyFileUpload(SoftDeletionModel):

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        null=True,
        unique=False,
        blank=True,
        default="file name"
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='company_file_uploads'
    )

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True
    )

    data_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=Utils.create_company_file_upload_path,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[validate_file]
    )

    comment = models.CharField(
        max_length=400,
        null=True,
        unique=False
    )

    file_size = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        null=True,
        unique=False,
        blank=True,
        default="null"
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        size = self.data_file.size
        power = 2**10
        n = 0
        power_labels = {0: '', 1: 'Kilo', 2: 'Mega', 3: 'Giga', 4: 'Tera'}
        while size > power:
            size /= power
            n += 1

        self.file_size = f"{size:.2f} {power_labels[n]}bytes"
        self.name = self.data_file.name

        super(CompanyFileUpload, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.data_file}, {self.user}'


@receiver(post_save, sender=CompanyFileUpload)
def email_report_details_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    ctx = {
        "firstname": instance.user.firstname,
        "timestamp": instance.timestamp,
        "fullname_and_email": f"{instance.user.firstname} {instance.user.othernames}",
        "subject": "File Upload",
        "recepient": instance.user.email,
        "email": instance.user.email,
        "url": instance.data_file.url,
        "comment": instance.comment
    }

    Utils.send_report_email(ctx)
```

**My serializer:**

```
class CompanyFileUploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(
        format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CompanyFileUpload
        fields = ["id",
                  "name",
                  "user",
                  "data_file",
                  "comment",
                  "file_size",
                  "timestamp"]

        extra_kwargs = {
            'file_size': {'read_only': True},
            'name': {'read_only': True}
        }
```

**My View:**

```
class CreateCompanyFileUploadAPI(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint for creating a Company file_upload

    Sample Response:

{
    "id": 3,
    "user": 4,
    "title": "This is an awesome file",
    "data_file": "https://{ url_to_some_storage :) }",
    "comment": "Well it should be awesome...",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-09T19:33:04.835268Z"
}
    """

    serializer_class = CompanyFileUploadSerializer


class ListCompanyFileUploadsAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint for viewing all Company file_uploads

    Sample Response:
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "user": 4,
        "title": "This is an awesome file",
        "data_file": "https://{ url_to_some_storage :) }",
        "comment": "Well it should be awesome...",
        "timestamp": "2021-06-09T19:33:04.835268Z"
    }
]
    """
    serializer_class = CompanyFileUploadSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend,)
    search_fields = ["title", "user__firstname"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user

        return CompanyFileUpload.objects.filter(user=user).order_by("-timestamp")


class RetrieveCompanyFileUploadDetailsAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint for reading a Company single file_upload details

    Sample Response:
{
    "id": 3,
    "user": 4,
    "title": "This is an awesome file",
    "data_file": "https:{ url_to_some_storage :) }",
    "comment": "Well it should be awesome...",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-09T19:33:04.835268Z"
}
    """
    serializer_class = CompanyFileUploadSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user

        return CompanyFileUpload.objects.filter(user=user)


class DeleteCompanyUploadedFileAPI(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint to delete already uploaded Company files from local/blob storage
    """
    serializer_class = CompanyFileUploadSerializer

    queryset = CompanyFileUpload.objects
    lookup_field = "pk"

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return CompanyFileUpload.objects.filter(user=user)


class UpdateCompanyUploadedFileAPI(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint for updating an uploaded company file details/content
{
    "id": 2,
    "user": 2,
    "title": "lnlnl",
    "data_file": "https:{ url_to_some_storage :) }",
    "comment": "Changed",
    "file_size": "86.25 Kilobytes",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-21T22:15:20.342044Z"
}
    """
    serializer_class = CompanyFileUploadSerializer
    queryset = CompanyFileUpload.objects
    lookup_field = "pk"

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.usclass CreateCompanyFileUploadAPI(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint for creating a Company file_upload

    Sample Response:

{
    "id": 3,
    "user": 4,
    "title": "This is an awesome file",
    "data_file": "https://{ url_to_some_storage :) }",
    "comment": "Well it should be awesome...",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-09T19:33:04.835268Z"
}
    """

    serializer_class = CompanyFileUploadSerializer


class ListCompanyFileUploadsAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint for viewing all Company file_uploads

    Sample Response:
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "user": 4,
        "title": "This is an awesome file",
        "data_file": "https://{ url_to_some_storage :) }",
        "comment": "Well it should be awesome...",
        "timestamp": "2021-06-09T19:33:04.835268Z"
    }
]
    """
    serializer_class = CompanyFileUploadSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend,)
    search_fields = ["title", "user__firstname"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user

        return CompanyFileUpload.objects.filter(user=user).order_by("-timestamp")


class RetrieveCompanyFileUploadDetailsAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint for reading a Company single file_upload details

    Sample Response:
{
    "id": 3,
    "user": 4,
    "title": "This is an awesome file",
    "data_file": "https://{ url_to_some_storage :) }",
    "comment": "Well it should be awesome...",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-09T19:33:04.835268Z"
}
    """
    serializer_class = CompanyFileUploadSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user

        return CompanyFileUpload.objects.filter(user=user)


class DeleteCompanyUploadedFileAPI(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint to delete already uploaded Company files from local/blob storage
    """
    serializer_class = CompanyFileUploadSerializer

    queryset = CompanyFileUpload.objects
    lookup_field = "pk"

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return CompanyFileUpload.objects.filter(user=user)


class UpdateCompanyUploadedFileAPI(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint for updating an uploaded company file details/content
{
    "id": 2,
    "user": 2,
    "title": "lnlnl",
    "data_file": "https://{ url_to_some_storage :) }",
    "comment": "Changed",
    "file_size": "86.25 Kilobytes",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-21T22:15:20.342044Z"
}
    """
    serializer_class = CompanyFileUploadSerializer
    queryset = CompanyFileUpload.objects
    lookup_field = "pk"

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user

        return CompanyFileUpload.objects.filter(user=user)er

        return CompanyFileUpload.objects.filter(user=user)
```

**Email method:**

```
class Utils:

    @staticmethod
    def send_report_email(ctx):
        """utility service to handle report upload details email """

        message = get_template('mail.html').render(ctx)
        msg = EmailMessage(
            ctx["subject"],
            message,
            os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_USER"),
            [ctx["recepient"]],
        )
        msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
        msg.send()
```

I have containerized the django-app and nginx server using docker compose. The storage is handled using an azure bulb container storage.

Now, **the question is, how do I turn this current FileUpload CRUD enpoints into a bulk File upload(or Directory upload) CRUD(at least for the create endpoint)?**
I tried working around the bulk serializer I found in this article; [Efficient Bulk Create with Django Rest Framework](https://medium.com/swlh/efficient-bulk-create-with-django-rest-framework-f73da6af7ddc), but though I found some success using it for the CRUD of other endpoints, I have woefully failed at implementing this method for the fileUplaod creation endpoint so far and would be very grateful if anyone can offer me any advice or viable solution.

*This Rest-API is for an enterprise system Software and efficiency is highly desired/necessary.*